# Python: cannot unpack non-iterable int object

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I am using python's `pandas` module to read in a .txt that looks as follows:

```
4.29999365676926    255.0
4.333326940930262   60.39473684210526
4.366660225091264   0.0
4.399993509252266   255.0
4.4333267934132685  0.0
4.46666007757427    0.0
4.499993361735272   0.0
4.533326645896274   255.0
4.566659930057276   0.0
```

Now, what I want to do is: Whenever the second column contains a value greater or equal to 230, save the index (the row number). Why is this important to me? Because later on, I want to create a list that only contains the timestamps (first column of the .txt) that belong to the rows in which the second column has a value >=230. Also, I perform operations on the second column.

Well, it is a little hard to explain, maybe the actual code helps clarifying the issue:

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 


VideoData = pd.read_csv('myFile.txt', sep='\t')
VideoPixelMean = VideoData.iloc[:,1].values.tolist() #this column contains the mean of the pixel intensities within a specified ROI
VideoPixelMean = [int(el) for el in VideoPixelMean]
VideoTimestamp = VideoData.iloc[:,0].values.tolist() #this column contains the time at which the mean of the pixel intensities within the ROI was calculated
VideoTimestamp = [int(el) for el in VideoTimestamp]

SpokeList = []
for idx,el in VideoPixelMean:
    if int(el) >= 230:   #I'm trying to detect the spokes of a wheel: whenever pixel intensities are >=230, there is a spoke within the ROI
        SpokeList.append(idx)

VideoVelocity = []
VelocityTime = []
for idx in range(0, len(SpokeList)):
    if idx == 0:
        VideoVelocity.append(0)
    else:
        framesPassed = SpokeList[idx] - SpokeList[idx-1]
        velocity = 2*np.pi/360 * 72 * 50 * framesPassed/30 #each wheel has 5 spokes (the angle between two spokes is 72°) and a radius of 50mm; fps = 30
        VideoVelocity.append(velocity)
        velocityTime = VideoTimestamp[idx]
        VelocityTime.append(velocityTime)
```

Anyways, the first 5 lines of my code have been modified in this way, because I am (still) getting the error: `cannot unpack non-iterable int object` for my first for-loop. But, why is my `VideoPixelMean` not iterable?

Can anyone help?

Comment: in your first for loop you are trying to unpack an int into two values (idx and el). Did you mean to use enumerate?